# Which Cloud Region Should I select for my blog site?

Tags: seo, server, geolocation, amazon-aws, ux

I currently have my blog set up with shared hosting(godaddy). After recent growth on traffic, I feel like, its time to get serious by hosting it to a better place, I am thinking about cloud obviously.

However, in amazon/digitalocean etc, I have to select the region where I want to host the site. As part of shared hosting it was hosted in US region, I guess. But as my site's traffic mostly based on Asia, I am thinking to choose a nearby location now, say, Singapore.

Though I know, its probably make sense to do so. But at the same time, I also don't want my North american visitors suffers, rather I want to grow more visitors in this area(I myself currently reside in Canada).

Just wondering if the decision moving the server to singapore region can be very bad for north american visitors or it will be kind of OK for now? Should I stick to a US based server for any reason? For User Experience/SEO perspective?

Comment: Also duplicate of [does server location matter](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27286/does-server-location-matter-in-same-country).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you mean "VPS" rather than cloud?

I do not know what your business is about, but it all depends on where your potential clients area. Asia generates a lot of traffic, that's for sure, but it's about the conversions. In my case, the traffic was very high but not really converting.

Having said the above, remember that you can improve page load time and user experience regardless of the server location. You should use a CDN and caching, and if the website's traffic is flying high, consider configuring your site on more than one server.