# What Ranks Better? Faster Server located in foreign country or Slower Server from same country?

Tags: seo, server, webserver, cdn, local-seo

95% of my website traffic is from India and 5% from USA.
What happens if I host my server with higher resources in USA or with lower resources in India. Will it have any effect on the ranking of my website?

I reserched and found this argument:
[Does server location matter in same country?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27286/does-server-location-matter-in-same-country)
Here @alfasin argues that servers with same resources would have better ranking if hosted in the same country but didn't say about the condition I mentioned above.

I want to host my server in USA as its cheaper to buy Host from USA than from India.

For refernce my website generally has 30K hits per day with over a million of pageviews per month.

Comment: Yea. The whole host your site in the same country thing is misguided. Some say it would be wise to locate a server nearer to your users to reduce network latency, however, that presumes that all networks are created equal. They are not. If you host with one of the big guys, you should see good results and the site speed will be fine even half way around the world. Most of your latency problems are likely in India whether your site is hosted there or in the U.S. The results could be similar. Always go with high quality first.

Answer (score 1):

The round trip time from India to USA is approx 250ms, so you need to consider the number of HTTP requests each page of your website makes, as this could increase the page load time dramatically. You also need to take into account the client (desktop, 3g or 4g mobile) and link speed, https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/mobile suggests a number of factors you need to take account for mobile clients to remain sub 1 second page load for above the fold content which I believe is a ranking factor.

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html also advises that page loading speed is a ranking factor, so you really should do anything to get it as low as possible.

Personally I'd want my customers to have the best experience, so I'd keep it physically as close as possible (there is a reason CDN's exist). AWS have CloudFront available in India now, and will have a AWS region there soon, I'd migrate to AWS in another region but using CloudFront in India, and then migrate the servers when the India region is up. Probably won't be the cheapest option, but it will be better.

Comment: Update - Mumbai AWS region now open.

Answer (score 0):

Faster server only means quick download times, Rankings is determined by your KEY words used to describe your website or product. Look into network marketing to get a better idea on getting ranked higher for the search words of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Change your site language to AMP HTML and do not worry about server locations. :)

Comment: Care to explain *why*?

Comment: About AMP HTML that replaces the need for regional server locations / for mobile and with tweaks for your full site: http://paloalto.ardanmichaelblum.com/accelerated-mobile-pages/amp-html/