# Does geographic location matter where a website is hosted?

Tags: web-hosting

I'm starting a couple different websites, 1 is completely personal, and 1 is only going to be for a small group of people across the USA. I found a web hosting company that I like, but their only available server is in Europe.  My sites don't need to be indexed by any search engine.

I found [this link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8198/does-it-matter-where-a-servers-physical-location-is) but not it didn't really answer my question. Would I be better finding a host that I didn't like as well in the USA, or using one that I liked in Europe?

Comment: Should not matter. Do what you are more comfortable with. Cheers!!